# Multiply i-th element with (j+1)-th element in python(3.7) lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists containing x- and y- coordinates of points, like the following:

```
x_vert = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]  
y_vert = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3]
```

The last item of each list is already the appended first item of each list, according to the calculation-algorithm.

What I want to do is the calculation of the area of an irregular-polygon. Therefore I need to multiply the i-th item of list *x_vert* with the (j+1)-th item of list *y_vert*.
So far I tried the following approaches:

```
x_vert_mul = [i * (j+1) for i in x_vertices for j in y_vertices]  
y_vert_mul = [i * (j+1) for i in y_vertices for j in x_vertices]
```

This returned a

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

So I tried another approach:

```
x_vert_mul = [i * (j+1) for i, j in zip(x_vertices, y_vertices)]
y_vert_mul = [i * (j+1) for i, j in zip(y_vertices, x_vertices)]
```

Which returned the same error as before. I assume the problem lies in the part *(j+1)*. Or do I have to do the multiplication in another way, since `*` insists a concatenation of two lists?
So my question is: How can I access the next item of a list and multiply it with the other desired value of the first list?

Desired Output:

```
x_vert_mul = [4, 10, 18, 28, 15]
y_vert_mul = [6, 12, 20, 30, 7]
```

In addition: I cannot import any modules. So I have to stay with built-ins.

Comment: why do you have separate I and j? are you trying to calculate using shoelace formula?

Comment: yes, that's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip` and list indexing:

```
In [1]: x_vert = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]

In [2]: y_vert = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3]

In [3]: x_vert_mul = [i*j for i, j in zip(x_vert[:-1], y_vert[1:])]

In [4]: y_vert_mul = [i*j for i, j in zip(y_vert[:-1], x_vert[1:])]

In [5]: x_vert_mul
Out[5]: [4, 10, 18, 28, 15]

In [6]: y_vert_mul
Out[6]: [6, 12, 20, 30, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem description is incorrect. What you meant was "multiply the `i-th` item of list `x_vert` with the `(i+1)-th` item of list `y_vert`". Also the code you claim to have tried won't raise any errors (it will simply give you the wrong answer).

Try this:

```
>>> [x_vert[i] * y_vert[i+1] for i in range(len(x_vert)-1)]
[4, 10, 18, 28, 15]
```

and

```
>>> [y_vert[i] * x_vert[i+1] for i in range(len(y_vert)-1)]
[6, 12, 20, 30, 7]
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the misleading problem description but happy that you still managed to provide a solution for my problem.